# How can javascript be stopped to wait for a deferred to finish?

Tags: jquery

I have a function which takes a parameter and does synchronous loadings.

I changed it to do an asynchronous jQuery.ajax call to retrieve data and call a callback. Old code (which cannot be modified) uses the same function and fails. I need to be able to retrieve the data both ways so async code can keep on running and old sync code can retrieve the cached data if async already loaded it, load it synchronously or wait for any async requests which are already running.

```
var ajaxQueries = {}
loadEngineData(fileId, callback) {
    var sync = callback == undefined;
    if (ajaxQueries[fileId]) {
        if (sync) {
            //Need to stop here and wait for ajaxQueries[fileId] to finish
            //Execution cannot continue! If we return before defered has ended here 3rd party scripts will fail.
            return data;
        }
        else {
            ajaxQueries[fileId].done(function(data){callback(data)});
        }
    }
    else {
        ajaxQueries[fileId] = $.ajax({
            async:!sync,
            type:'GET',
            url:fileId2Name(fileId),
            data:null,
            dataType:'text',
        });
        if (sync) {
            var _data = undefined;
            ajaxQueries[fileId].done(function(data){_data=data});
            return _data;
        }
        ajaxQueries[fileId].done(function(data){callback(data);});
    }
}
```

If an old script calls the function the ajax query will run synchronously and all subsequent calls will use the deferred `.done` and `.fail` and everything will be fine.

```
var enginePhyData = loadEngineData('physics');
//Do stuff
```

If a new script calls the function first and during this loading an old script tries to load data from the same file, I end with a situation where the deferred ajax query in `ajaxQueries[fileId]` is running asynchronously and I have to wait for it to finish loading the data to avoid breaking the existing libs.

I simplified `loadEngineData` to keep the question focussed. Otherwise it's a bit more complex and allows calling a list of files to load in parallel

```
loadEngineData(['geometry', 'scripts'], function() {
    var phy = loadEngineData('physics');
    var geo = loadEngineData('geometry');
    var scr = loadEngineData('scripts');

    //run the async function;
});
loadEngineData('physics', function() {
    //run the async function;
});

//...
//in the scripts file

var phy = loadEngineData('physics');
//here phy might be undefined if this file went through eval() before `loadEngineData('physics',...)` was called;
```

I could modernize the code, but the issue is that some files are shared across projects and run in different environments. I can't currently modify the old scripts without forking the dependencies.

Comment: you're trying to make asynchronous code synchronous, which will not work. You can't just stop code execution until x condition without possible page-breaking side effects.

Comment: Your options are: Leave the old method alone and make a new method so that the old method continues to work synchronously, or modify the way the old code works to make it work asynchronously.

Comment: @KevinB : From what I understand calling `$.ajax({async:false,...});` stops code execution. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, it does. but can you do that in your case? It almost looks as-if what you currently have should work (with the addition of return `$.parseJSON(ajaxQueries[fileId].responseText)` assuming the request always enters the second half of the if statement, which brings the question of what are you actually asking for?

Comment: If an old script calls the function first to retrieve needed data we will get `$.ajax({async:false,...});` otherwise no. And you say that in the later case there is no way to wait for the deferred to end before resuming? I will edit the question to get it right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot stop the execution of javascript while waiting for some asynchronous ajax call to finish.  Javascript simply doesn't work that way.

Instead, you have to rework the way you program so that code that wants to wait for an asychronous ajax call to be completed will execute via a callback function, not synchronously after the ajax call executes.

Answer (score 1):

You're close, you just need to return the responseText if it is a sync request.

```
return data
```

becomes

```
return ajaxQueries[fileId].responseText;
```

since the request was synchronous, there's no need to wait, the browser has already waited for the response.

```
var ajaxQueries = {}
loadEngineData(fileId, callback) {
    var sync = callback == undefined;
    if (ajaxQueries[fileId]) {
        if (sync) {
            return ajaxQueries[fileId].responseText;
        }
        else {
            ...
```

Comment: What I'm missing is the code to wait for an async request to complete if a script calls the function expecting a return response. The ajax query in `ajaxQueries[fileId]` might not have ended yet as it could have been launched asynchronously, in that case i'm returning `undefined` and the script fails.

Comment: It'l never get into that section if sync is false, sending it into the else where it properly handles an async request, meaning if it's sync data will be returned from the method both the first time and subsequent times, and if it's async, the callback that is supplied will be called when it is requested. Now, if you made a sync request and then used it as async (or vice versa), you may run into problems.