# Why does not global variable hold value

Tags: javascript

I can't understand, why variable `preset` doesn't hold any value at the end of function `setValue()` execution.

```
 function setValue(_provider, _index) {
        var preset = {};
        _provider.getItems(function (error, items) {
            ErrorUtility.logError(error);
            preset = items[_index].value;
            //preset contains correct object
            _provider.value(preset);
        });
        return preset; // preset contains empty object.
    }
```

In the `_provider.getItems` `preset` setted and contains correct object, but out of `_provider.getItems()` scope, `preset` holds empty object, as it was initialized, and `setValue()` returns it.

Comment: it's asynchronous problem.

Comment: Thanks, I think I got it. So, what would be you advice?

Comment: I think you can get a callback and call that with value of `preset`.

Comment: It depends what you need to do with the result; you could just make it a void method and make a third argument for setValue a delegate, which in it's place be called within getItems

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because "return preset;" executes earlier then "preset = items[_index].value;". Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14444274/how-can-javascript-be-stopped-to-wait-for-a-deferred-to-finish).